# Не получается padding

Tags: html, css

Не получается настроить `padding` для `Middle sidebar` и `bottom sidebar` , `padding` для `Top sidebar` работает, для остальных нет что я делаю не так?

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DimaWorld/qqwwpoLp/2/embedded/#Result)

Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DimaWorld/qqwwpoLp/2/embedded/#Result

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/xv6f44bv1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте Вашу верстку на валидность, как html, так и css файлы!!!

У Вас там пропущены `;`

```css
body {
 background-image: url("img/back.png");  
 font-size: 88%;
 font-family: Arial;
 text-align: left;
}

.body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;         // space between
 clear: both;
} 

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.Logo {
 width: 100px; 
 height: 100px;
}

a:link, a:visited {

}

a:hover, a:active {
 
}

.mainheader img {
 width: 10%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 2% 0;
}

.mainheader nav {
 background-color: #37598B;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.mainheader nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainheader nav ul li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
 color: #FFF;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 15px 25px;
 height: 50px;
}

.mainheader nav a:hover, .mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
 background-color: #E3A2FF;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.mainheader nav ul li a {
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainContent {
 line-height: 25px;  // space between lines of paragraph
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

}

.content {
 width: 60%; 
 float: left; 
}


.topcontent {
 background-color:  #FFF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 3% 5%;   
 margin-top: 2%;
}


.bottomcontent {
 background-color:  #FFF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 3% 5%;   
 margin-top: 2%;
}


 .top-sidebar { 
 width: 27%;;
 float: left; 
 background-color:  #FFF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 1.5% 0 2% 3%;
 padding: 2% 3%; 
 
}


.middle-sidebar {
 width: 27%;
 float: left; 
 background-color:  #FFF; 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 3%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 30px;
 
}


.bottom-sidebar {
 width: 27%;
 float: left; 
 background-color:  #FFF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 3%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 padding: 2% 3%;

}


.mainFooter {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;  
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:  #37598B;
  margin: 2% 0;
}

.mainFooter p {
 width: 90%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 2% auto;
}
```

```html
<head>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"> </script>

 <title>  My Web Page </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body class="body">

<header class="mainheader">
  <img class="Logo" alt=Logo src="img/Logo.jpg">   

  <nav> <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Home      </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> About     </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Contacts  </a></li>
  </ul> </nav>
</header>

<div class="mainContent"> 
  <div class="content">
    <article class="topcontent"> 
      <header>  
        <h2> <a href="#" title="First post"> First post </a> </h2>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="post-info"> This Post was written by me </p>
      </footer>

      <content>
        <p>Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. 
        </p>
        <p>Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. 
        </p>
         <footer>  <p> Author: Josh Anderson </p>  </footer>
      </content>
    </article>


      <article class="bottomcontent"> 
      <header>  
        <h2> <a href="#" title="second post"> Second post </a> </h2>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="post-info"> This Post was written by me </p>
      </footer>

      <content>
        <p>Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. You will be directly involved in creating... and producing lighting, environments, characters and high-resolution 3D objects. You must be able to respect the design uploaded by our 2D concept        
        </p>
        <p>Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. You will be directly involved in creating... and producing lighting, environments, characters and high-resolution 3D objects. You must be able to respect the design uploaded by our 2D concept        
        </p>
         <footer>  <p> Author: Josh Anderson </p>  </footer>
      </content>
    </article>

  </div>
</div>

<aside class="top-sidebar">   
  <article> 
    <h2> Top sidebar </h2>
    <p>Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. You will be directly involved in creating... and producing lighting, environments, characters and high-resolution 3D objects. You must be able to respect the design uploaded by our 2D concept        
    </p>
  </article>
</aside>


<aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article> 
    <h2> Middle sidebar </h2>
    <p>  Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. You will be directly involved in creating... and producing lighting, environments, characters and high-resolution 3D objects. You must be able to respect the design uploaded by our 2D concept
    </p>
  </article>
</aside>

<aside class="bottom-sidebar"> 
  <article> 
    <h2> bottom sidebar </h2>
    <p> Responsibilities: You will be responsible for creating and developing 3D models for packaging. You will be directly involved in creating... and producing lighting, environments, characters and high-resolution 3D objects. You must be able to respect the design uploaded by our 2D concept 
    </p>
  </article>
</aside>
 


<footer class="mainFooter">
    <p> Copiright &copy; <a href="" title="firstwebdesign"> firstwebdesign  </a></p>
</footer>


</body>
```

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо

Comment: @DimaWorld, you are welcome ; )